# jQuery UI's greedy droppable not working as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a list of draggables than can be dropped inside a droppable and when this happens, the draggables are cloned and converted to droppables.

This new droppables are greedy but when they receive a draggable, both drop events are fired (the drop event from the draggable and the drop event from the droppable area)

What I'm doing wrong? I need the event to fire only once (from the new droppable)

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3118zjg1/): drag and drop an item into the red area, then drag another item and drop it into the item you already dropped. See the console log.

HTML

```
<div id="main_droppable"></div>

<ul>
  <li class="item" data-id="1">1</li>
  <li class="item" data-id="2">2</li>
  <li class="item" data-id="3">3</li>
  <li class="item" data-id="4">4</li>
  <li class="item" data-id="5">5</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(".item").data("active", false);

$(".item").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    appendTo: "#main_droppable",
    scroll: false,
    start: function(event, ui)
    {
        if($(this).data("active") == false)
        {
            $(this).fadeTo(100, 0.2);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    },
    revert: function(is_valid_drop)
    {
        if(!is_valid_drop)
        {
            $(this).fadeTo(100, 1).data("active", false);

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).data("active", true);
        }
    }
});

$("#main_droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui)
    {
        console.log("drop main");

        addNewItem(ui.helper);

        return false;
    }
});

function addNewItem($oldItem)
{
    var $newItem = $oldItem.clone(false).fadeTo(100, 1).data("active", true);

    $oldItem.remove();

    $newItem.draggable({
        containment: "parent",
    });

    $newItem.droppable({
        greedy: true,
        drop: function(event, ui)
        {
            console.log("drop item");

            $(this).fadeTo(100, 0, function()
            {
                var $originalItem = $("ul").find(".item[data-id=" + $(this).data("id") + "]");

                $originalItem.fadeTo(100, 1).data("active", false);

                $("#main_droppable").find(".item[data-id=" + $originalItem.data("id") + "]").remove();
            });

            addNewItem(ui.helper);
        }
    });

  $("#main_droppable").append($newItem);
}
```

CSS

```
#main_droppable
{
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.item
{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: So the item should not move back to the draggable again in case you have done a overlap drop?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Why it shouldn't? Besides, the point is the double drop event

Comment: I have never worked with droppables so just trying to understand the problem, and understand what is the expected behaviour you want to see?

Comment: If I understand you correctly @Matias Canepa, you wants the blue draggables to be dropables too so you can have visually nested droppables right?

Comment: @RobertUdah kind of... the draggables are converted to droppables indeed. But they are not greedy, and I want them to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well...it had to do with a particular class...

When I dropped the draggable and cloned it, the `ui-draggable-dragging` class stayed in place. So in order to make it work I had to remove it, then everything worked as expected.

I change this line:

```
var $newItem = $oldItem.clone(false).fadeTo(100, 1).data("active", true);
```

Into this one:

```
var $newItem = $oldItem.clone(false).fadeTo(100, 1).data("active", true).removeClass("ui-draggable-dragging");
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3118zjg1/1/

Answer (score -1):

I think the dragables actually become greedy but the `#main_droppable` event still gets triggered because:

When you place another `.item` element on top of another, the intended action for dropping a `.item` into another `.item` gets triggered.

```
    $newItem.droppable({
            greedy: true,
            drop: function(event, ui)
            {
                console.log("drop item");
                ...
```

but this original element gets removed further down the code anyway..

```
    $(this).fadeTo(100, 0, function()
       {
        var $originalItem = $("ul").find(".item[data-id=" + $(this).data("id") + "]");

        $originalItem.fadeTo(100, 1).data("active", false);

        $("#main_droppable").find(".item[data-id=" + $originalItem.data("id") + "]").remove();
        ...
```

You're effectively replacing the original item with the new one hence the `#main_droppable` event getting triggered.

I can't say I know how to fix the unintentional side effect without changing your intended behaviour, but hopefully you have a better clue as to why the `greedy` attribute seems to not work.